# What happens with println() statements when the program is not open in command window?

Tags: java, jar

I was wondering what happens with the `System.out.println()` statements when a Java program is not open from console but for example from a .jar file.

Comment: When you say "open from .jar file", do you mean by double-clicking the .jar file? Because you can "Open" (aka "Run") a Java program in a .jar file from the command prompt too, using `java -jar path/to/program.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. The outputstream (and errorstream) can be redirected to a file, but otherwise they will just disappear into the void.